# A way to enter standart letters using shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

So from time to time my letters <kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> stop working on my keyboard, which means I have to type using help from screen keyboard. I am looking for a way to assign these characters to shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for <kbd>O</kbd> and etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try in console xdotool:

xdotool keydown ctrl  click p keyup ctrl

put it in bash script, and use shortcuts to execute the script.